# Org sql header args dont seem to work why?

Tags: org-babel, sql

Can anyone explain why this does not work, i want to set the parameters global to the current document using PROPERTY but this does not work and results in this error.

(wrong-type-argument stringp nil)

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args:sql :engine oracle 
#+PROPERTY: header-args:sql+ :dbhost 172.17.0.6
#+PROPERTY: header-args:sql+ :dbport 1521 
#+PROPERTY: header-args:sql+ :dbuser db_user
#+PROPERTY: header-args:sql+ :dbpassword db_pass
#+PROPERTY: header-args:sql+ :database XE

#+BEGIN_SRC sql
SELECT * FROM dual;
#+END_SRC
```

How ever this does work but i need to copy it for each block.

```
#+header: :engine oracle 
#+header: :dbhost 172.17.0.6
#+header: :dbport 1521 
#+header: :dbuser db_user 
#+header: :dbpassword db_pass 
#+header: :database XE
#+BEGIN_SRC sql
SELECT * FROM dual;
#+END_SRC
```

Comment: Hmm it works for me. Have you tried under emacs -Q?

Comment: no i will give it a try, perhaps its oracle specific

Comment: did you mean -q instead of quick mode either way i dont seem to get org and ob-sql using that param to test with.

Comment: I mean it might be something in your config breaking it. I copy & pasted your first example into a test file and C-c C-c each property line without issue, Although I couldn't run the SQL source (having not set it up), C-c C-v I showed all the header args where set as expected.

Comment: C-c C-v thats sounds handy whats that bound to think it might be different on my setup org-babel-load-in-session is what mine is mapped to.

Comment: also worth noting a property draw seems to work as well, just not the headers

Comment: You can enable debugging and see where in the backtrace the (wrong-type-argument stringp nil) is coming from.

Comment: Okay just figured out the issue probably expected behaviour, I need to C-c C-c the PROPERTY block before C-c C-c the source code block else it does not pick up the settings, wonder if there is a way to automate that ?